# How can I enable autocomplete for a global grunt install in Phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I am hoping to get autocompletion within PhpStorm while I am configuring `Gruntfile.js` files.
I believe I am not gettting code assistance for `grunt` methods like `grunt.loadNpmTasks`, `grunt.initConfig` etc because grunt is installed *globally* in my home dir `/home/user/npm/lib/node_modules` and not available locally in My project directory.

How can I enable code assistance (autocompletion etc) in phpstorm?

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of PhpStorm (2016.3), follow these steps:

1. Navigate to Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries
2. Press the "Download..." button.
3. Make sure "TypeScript community stubs" is selected from the dropdown at the top.
4. Find and select "gruntjs" and click the "Download and Install" button. The IDE will download the type definition file and the window will close when it's done.
5. Make sure the checkbox next to "gruntjs-DefinitelyTyped" is checked, then press "OK".

Next, open up your Gruntfile.js and add the following docblock at the top, right before the module.exports line:

```
/**
 * @param {IGrunt} grunt
 */
module.exports = function (grunt) {
```